# Reverse infinity scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, infinite-scroll

I want to make messenger, where messages are showing like in a chat where scroll from bottom to top. And when you scroll to the top of limit, system will load more messages.

The problem in control position of `scrollTop` after load new items. How to count this position?

- *given example in context of meteor - but answer in pure js (theory) will be helpful to)*

HTML

```
<template name='chatBox'>
    <div class='chat-box'><!--viewport-->

        {{> chatBoxItem}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name='chatBoxItem'>
    <div class='chat-box-wrapper'><!--content block-->
        {{#each messeges}}
            <p>{{messege}}</p> <!--each messege-->
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.chatBox.onRendered(function() {
    // viewport template

    $('.chat-box').scroll(function(e) {
        var chatBoxHeight = $('.chat-box').innerHeight(); 
        var wrapperHeight = $('#chat-box-wrapper').innerHeight();
        var chatBoxScroll = $('.chat-box').scrollTop();

        var currentScrollFromBottom = wrapperHeight - chatBoxScroll; //don't sure if this formula is correct but it's count how many pixels was scrolled from bottom to top

        if (currentScrollFromBottom  == wrapperHeight && MESSAGES_LIMIT < amountOfMessages) {

            //here some code to increase limit of queue

        }
    });


Template.chatBoxItem.onRendered(function () {
    // content template

    var $heightOfBlock = $('#chat-box-wrapper').height();
    $('.chat-box').scrollTop($heightOfBlock); 
    // Here I have the most problem, 
    // I need to scroll to bottom when page is load (work good)                     
    // but after loaded new items, it's need to stand still, but   
    // it's not. I don't know which formula i need     
    // to use to count current scroll position 

});
```

Maybe this example are wrong at all, but I don't understand how to make infinity scroll in reverse - from bottom to top.

UPDATE:

I found this formula, but it's for normal scrolling, how I need to rebuild this for reverse scroll?

```
$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this with jquery:

```
var st=$("#chat").scrollTop();
$("#chat").prepend(me);
$("#chat").scrollTop(st+me.outerHeight());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lhmn07rg/8/